How to limit number of table A lines in a select with more joins table B, table C,
I have more tables that are joined together:
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {   class Document extends AT_ModelDb {       static associate(models) {       // define association here       models.Document.belongsTo       (models.DocumentType              ,{as: 'type'                     , foreignKey : 'type_id'            , targetKey  : "id"                       });       models.Document.belongsTo       (models.DocumentStatus            ,{as: 'status'                   , foreignKey : 'status_id'          , targetKey  : "id"                       });       models.Document.belongsTo       (models.Document                  ,{as: 'documentLinked'           , foreignKey : "documentLinked_id"  , targetKey  : 'id'                       });       models.Document.belongsTo       (models.DocumentBatch             ,{as: 'batch'                    , foreignKey : "batch_id"           , targetKey  : 'id'                       });       models.Document.belongsTo       (models.Project                   ,{as: 'project'                  , foreignKey : "project_id"         , targetKey  : 'id'                       });       models.Document.belongsTo       (models.Budget                    ,{as: 'budget'                   , foreignKey : 'budget_id'          , targetKey  : "id"                       });       models.Document.hasMany         (models.Document_AircraftConfig   ,{as: 'documentsAircraftConfigs' , foreignKey : "document_id"        , targetKey  : 'id'                       });       models.Document.hasMany         (models.Attachment                ,{as: 'attachments'              , foreignKey : "document_id"        , targetKey  : 'id'                       });       models.Document.hasMany         (models.DocumentNote              ,{as: 'notes'                    , foreignKey : "document_id"        , targetKey  : 'id'                       });   

When I ask sequelize.findAll I want to have , for example, 15 items about my main table (here Document)
When I request sequelize.findAnd I want to have, for example, 15 elements on my main table (here Document) regardless of the number of rows retrieved by the select and joins.
The "limit" clause of the "select" is therefore not appropriate.
I found a way to do it in PostgreSql:
select *
    
from (
SELECT  dense_rank() over (order by "Document"."id") as "idx","Document"."type_id", "Document"."reference", "Document"."title", "Document"."status_id", "Document"."ata_code", "Document"."ataAH_code", "Document"."issue", "Document"."lead_code", "Document"."documentLinked_id", "Document"."batch_id", "Document"."project_id", "Document"."creationDateAH", "Document"."statusAH", "Document"."budget_id", "Document"."toBeAnalysed", "Document"."createdBy_code", "Document"."updatedBy_code", "Document"."id", "Document"."deleted", "Document"."createdAt", "Document"."updatedAt"
    ,"criterias"."code" AS "criterias.code", "criterias"."title" AS "criterias.title", "criterias"."createdBy_code" AS "criterias.createdBy_code", "criterias"."updatedBy_code" AS "criterias.updatedBy_code", "criterias"."id" AS "criterias.id",  
[...] 
    FROM "Documents" AS "Document" 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ( "Documents_Criterias" AS "criterias->Document_Criteria" INNER JOIN "Criterias" AS "criterias" ON "criterias"."id" = "criterias->Document_Criteria"."criteria_id") ON "Document"."id" = "criterias->Document_Criteria"."document_id" 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN "Documents_AircraftConfigs" AS "documentsAircraftConfigs" ON "Document"."id" = "documentsAircraftConfigs"."document_id" 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN "Document_Notes" AS "notes" ON "Document"."id" = "notes"."document_id" 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN "Document_Status" AS "status" ON "Document"."status_id" = "status"."id" 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN "Document_Types" AS "type" ON "Document"."type_id" = "type"."id" 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN "Projects" AS "project" ON "Document"."project_id" = "project"."id" 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN "Budgets" AS "budget" ON "Document"."budget_id" = "budget"."id" 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN "Documents" AS "documentLinked" ON "Document"."documentLinked_id" = "documentLinked"."id" 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN "Document_Batches" AS "batch" ON "Document"."batch_id" = "batch"."id" 
    
    WHERE "status"."code" < '25' 
    AND "Document"."deleted" = false 
) as "docs"
    where "idx" <= 15
     

But how to get Sequelize to give me this sql command.
I think it would be wise for this feature to be integre a sequelize, for example by setting a parameter more a findAll , different from the "limit" and which would make sequelize understand that we want limit only on the main table.And sequelize would generate a sql order different from the one it currently generates.
example:  limitOnMainTable: 15
But maybe it already exists, since this feature is very useful when paging.
Do you have a solution to offer me ?

You can try subQuery: true which applies the limit to the inner query (main table).
For example, assuming Document is the main table and DocumentType as sub table. The following code
const result = await Document.findAll({
  include: DocumentType,
  limit: 2,
  subQuery: true
});

will create a query like this.
SELECT 
  "Documents".*, 
  "DocumentTypes"."id" AS "DocumentTypes.id", 
  ... 
FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      "Documents"."id", 
      ...
    FROM 
      "Documents" AS "Documents" 
    WHERE 
      ("Documents"."deletedAt" IS NULL) 
    LIMIT 
      2
  ) AS "Documents" 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN "DocumentTypes" AS "DocumentTypes" ON "Documents"."id" = "DocumentTypes"."DocumentId" 
  AND (
    "DocumentTypes"."deletedAt" IS NULL
  );

The limit is applied to the main table and all associated sub table's records are fetched.
